# DRb, "who called me" method

Tags: ruby, uri, drb

In a DRbserver, how can I see who called a method?
I want to log the ip and port from anyone who calls a certain method.
something like

`def who

  uri = <DRb method here>

  puts uri

end`

Is this functionality available in DRb?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will use acl with this ->
[DRb method access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401982/drb-method-access/6446960#6446960)